# simple ajax using json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

ok so im just struggling  passing json with my jquery ajax

```
var values  = {"name":$("#folderName").val(),"dir":directory};
var valstring = JSON.stringify(values);
var user = {json:valstring};
$.ajax({
    url: "makeFolder.php",      
    data:user,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(n) {
        alert(n);
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
    }
});
```

then in my php

```
$json = $_REQUEST['json'];
$json = stripslashes($json);
$jsonobj = json_decode($json);
echo $jsonobj->name;
```

mean this should work shouldn't it? I'm probably doing something really stupid somewhere, i am however dumbfouded
it outputs html tags instead of the echo, when i take way all the post queries in my php it works 100%

Comment: even if you guys give me a different way to save my variables and access them in php, just need to get this to work

Comment: It's good idea to not using `$_REQUEST` in PHP, use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead.

Comment: yeah, sorry, it was origanlly $_POST its just one of the thing i changed in attempt to fix it

Comment: maybe im just sending it in a dumb way?

Comment: Can you describe exactly how it's not working? All you've said so far is that you're struggling, that this should work and that you're probably doing something stupid - but none of these things help the community debug the problem. Is there an error message?

Comment: um it just outputs html tags instead of the echo, when i take way all the post queries in my php it works 100%

Comment: so it has to be how i save and retrieve the data right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough information to really know what you're problem is, but given the information available I'm suspicious of this line:

```
contentType: false
```

... according to the [`jQuery.ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the `contentType` argument should be of type String, so I don't think `false` is an acceptable value.

Especially since you've also specified `processData: false`.

For example, check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6JkZk/ Using something like firebug, you can see that the AJAX request's body just contains this:

```
[object Object]
```

The server isn't receiving your `json` data at all. If you remove `processData: false` like so http://jsfiddle.net/6JkZk/1/ the AJAX request contains the actual POST parameters specified with the `data` argument.

You should only be setting `processData: false` when you're providing a `String` to the `data` argument, or when the object you provide has a `toString()` method, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/pDrUX/

Comment: nope still breaks.   Is there anything else i can upload to make my example more clear?

Comment: I think the issue is both `contentType: false` and `processData: false` in conjunction.

Comment: @user1752451 - I've provided some jsfiddle links which should help you understand what's happening. Because you've specified `processData: false` jQuery is using the `toString()` method of your object literal to populate the AJAX request body, except the default `toString()` method just creates the string `[object Object]` - effectively discarding your data.

Answer (score 0):

You must stringify the whole object you are sending to the server:

```
var user = JSON.stringify({"json": values});
```

Comment: What you get when `print_r($_POST['json']);`?

Comment: well cuz im using ajax, and have a alert statement in my success, it outputs a bunch of html tags, like when php generally breaks

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
var values  = '{"name": "' + $("#folderName").val() + '", "dir": "' + directory + '"}';
```